# Why I got different result out of console.log(this) from REPL

Tags: node.js

```
//test.js
console.log(this);
```

By executing the test.js with command '**node test.js**', I got result of '**{}**'. But by executing the same code in REPL, I got tons of system information. Why this difference? Is it because of my configuration of Node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different execution contexts.

In node, any file you require is a module that has its own scope, by default an empty object (hence the {}), until you export something.

The repl, on the other hand, is its own execution context with a bunch of stuff already attached to it. You can even set things up to attach to it yourself (e.g. Convenient functions)